# adb pull ,unicode character files

Tags: android, unicode, cmd, adb

In windows cmd, I typed,

```
adb pull /sdcard/1/이름 D:\wspace
```

('이름' is non-ascii unicode character)

so, an error occurred

```
C:\>adb pull /sdcard/1/이름 D:\wspace
remote object '/sdcard/1/이름' does not exist
```

how to pull unicode character files?

Comment: try running `chcp 65001` before your `adb pull`

Answer (score 0):

I just want to post this as an answer, for more visibility. The answer is originally posted as a comment by user @AlexP above. Upvote him.

To allow Unicode in file names, type

```
chcp 65001
```

and only after that type `adb pull`.

I've checked it now with Chinese and it works. Codepage 65001 is the way Unicode is denoted in Windows.

Or just use Powershell.